# Is it possible non-trivial solution for these equations?

Tags: equation-solving

```
sol = Solve[{
   -I*Ω1*σab - I*Ω2*σac + I*Ω1*σba + I*Ω2*σca == 0, 
   I*Ω1*σab - I*Ω1*σba - I*E^(-I*Δk*z)*Ωμ*σbc + I*E^(-I*Δk* z)*Ωμ*σcb == 0, 
   σaa + σbb + σcc == 1, 
   - Γab*σab - I*Ω1*σaa + I*Ω1*σbb - I*E^(-I*Δk*z)*Ωμ*σac + I*Ω2*σcb == 0,
   -Γac*σac - I*Ω2*σaa + I*Ω2*σcc - I*E^(-I*Δk*z)*Ωμ*σab + I*Ω1*σbc == 0, 
   -Γcb*σcb + I*E^(-I*Δk*z)*Ωμ*σbb - I*E^(-I*Δk*z)*Ωμ*σcc + 
     I*Ω2*σab - I*Ω1*σca == 0, 
   -Γab*σba + I*Ω1* σaa - I*Ω1*σbb - I*Ω2*σbc + 
     I*E^(I*Δk*z)*Ωμ*σca == 0, 
   -Γca*σca + I*Ω2*σaa - I*Ω2*σcc + I*E^(I*Δk*z)*Ωμ*σba - 
     I*Ω1*σcb == 0, 
   -Γcb*σbc - I*E^(I*Δk*z)*Ωμ*σbb + I*E^(I*Δk*z)*Ωμ*σcc - 
     I*Ω2*σba + I*Ω1*σac == 0}, 
  {σaa, σbb, σcc, σab, σba, σac, σca, σbc, σcb}]
```

Comment: After `Simplify` this evaluates to `{{σaa -> 1/3, σbb -> 1/3, σcc -> 1/3, σab -> 0, 
     σba -> 0, σac -> 0, σca -> 0, 
    σbc -> 0, σcb -> 0}}`. Is this what you are calling the trivial solution?

Comment: yes...  But i don't want this answers.  I need some expression in all terms. Can you suggest whether  is it possible or not?  @Bob Hanlon.